# Path traversal exploit

Tags: webserver, apache, directory-traversal

I have an Apache server which seems to be vulnerable to path traversal, because when I test this URL: `http://localhost/ati/../test.txt`

it will be changed to the this: `http://localhost/test.txt` 
and the server shows the contents of `test.txt` file.

However, when I test this URL:  `http://localhost/ati/../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/apache2/apach2.conf` it will be changed to: `http://localhost/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and therefore the server gives a `404 Not found response` and does not show the content of `apache2.conf` file.

My first question is: Does it mean that I am secure against path traversal attack regarding the fact that I have not changed any default settings of the Apache on my server?

And my second question is: why the server does not allow to traverse beyond the root of the web server folder? I.e. why can't I access outer files than localhost folder on my web server? How can I exploit path traversal if my server is vulnerable?

Comment: Default Apache config should protect against this. Scripts are generally able to access files outside of the document root, I would focus most of my energy there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache itself should not serve files outside the configured `DocumentRoot`.

The behavior you are describing is most likely caused by the browser, which transforms the URLs before sending them to the server.

If you use an intercepting proxy, you will notice that for `http://localhost/ati/../test.txt`, the browser actually requests `http://localhost/test.txt` and for `http://localhost/ati/../../../../../../../../../../../etc/apache2/apach2.conf`, `http://localhost/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is sent to the server.

If you want to check the path traversal vulnerability you should use a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Use Telnet to actually send your malicious request. As Dinu S pointed out, the browser is mangling your request, and Apache should not be serving these files AT ALL. To check:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 <server-port>
```

Then manually type in the request:

```
 GET /../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/apache2/apach2.conf HTTP/1.1
```

If it responds with your apache.conf file, then you are vulnerable. If you're aren't, it should respond with a 404 or 503.

Comment: I did what Ohnana said, i.e. I telnet to the server and request apache2.conf manually, it respond me with 408 Request time-out. How should I interpret this response??

Comment: By the way, I have another question from Dinu S:If this behavior is caused by my browser, can I use some encodings of "../", for example I use "..%c0%af" instead of "../" in order to bypass my browser checks and exploit path traversal vulnerability?